# Doctrine JOIN ... ON ... in annotations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm searching how to have an entity history (or versioning) using Doctrine.

Here are my tables (the column "code" identifies the entity and the "flag" identifies the last version):

User

```
+--------+-------------+------+
| Column |    Type     |  PK  |
+--------+-------------+------+
| id     | integer     | true |
| code   | integer     |      |
| flag   | boolean     |      |
| name   | string(255) |      |
+--------+-------------+------+
```

Post

```
+----------+----------+------+
|  Column  |   Type   |  PK  |
+----------+----------+------+
| id       | integer  | true |
| code     | integer  |      |
| flag     | boolean  |      |
| userCode | integer  |      |
| content  | longtext |      |
+----------+----------+------+
```

Here are my values :

User

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | code | flag | name |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | true | foo  |
|  2 |    2 | true | bar  |
+----+------+------+------+
```

Post

```
+----+------+-------+----------+----------------+
| id | code | flag  | userCode |    content     |
+----+------+-------+----------+----------------+
|  1 |    1 | false |        1 | First version  |
|  2 |    1 | false |        1 | Second version |
|  3 |    1 | true  |        2 | Third version  |
+----+------+-------+----------+----------------+
```

In this case, I have 3 version of my post, it was edited twice.

Using Doctrine (and Symfony), I would have a `joinColumns` with the `ON` specified in my User class :

```
class User{

    /**
      * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="author")
      * @JoinTable(name="user_posts",
      *    joinColumns={JoinColumn(name="user_code", referencedColumnName="code")
      *    inversedJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="post_code", referencedColumnName="code", on="flag=true")} <-- My ON parameter
      * )
      */
    private $posts
```

Is there a simple way to have this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have a history for all my entities and log them in a entityLog entity. I use a entity subscriber and when any entity update i insert a row with the entity name, timestamp, login user etc. Then just i just filter this rows like last 5 changes, by user or by entity for statistics reasons.

You can set one such external subscriber to listen to all entity changes and run your code like [documentation suggest](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers) or (for changes in a properties of a specific entity only) create a function with annotation in your entity class to use the [Lifecycle Callback](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-callbacks). For the second case don't forget the annotation `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` in your class otherwise it is not going to work.